# Blank screen on emulator when trying to view video? Android

Tags: android, video, screen, emulation

i've been trying to play my .3pg files on an android emulator (2.3.3), however all i get is a blank screen? Anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = null;
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaplayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(176, 144);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaplayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/sample.3gp");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaplayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaplayer.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}